# Gradle - configuration for sibling and interlinked projects

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I'm try to configure sibling projects with several dependencies (I'm talking about project dependencies, not artifact dependencies)

So the structure is something like:

```
A (needs B)
B (needs C)
C
```

I need to set correctly these dependencies. In particular, I'm using the Eclipse integration, so the goal is to get `Gradle -> Refresh all` set the correct dependencies among the relative Eclipse projects (however, I believe this question is independent of Eclipse).
Notice that there is only a logical hierarchical layout, not physical (and it will stay that way).

I have read about the use of `includeFlat`, but probably I'm still missing something.
If we look only at `B` and `C`, then I can have them work correctly, by:

- In `B/settings.gradle` : `includeFlat 'C'`
- In `B/build.gradle` : `compile project(':C')`

This works fine for `B`.

Now, `A` needs `B`. So what I thought was: I just need to do the same thing between `A` and `B`:

- In `A/settings.gradle` : `includeFlat 'B'`
- In `A/build.gradle` : `compile project(':B')`

I did expect that when refreshing `A`, the transitive dependency `A -> B -> C` would work, but somewhere it breaks and I get:

```
Project with path ':C' could not be found in project ':B'
```

What I'm guessing is that `B/settings.gradle` is not being read. Why is that?
Could someone tell me what I am not understanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a Gradle multi-project build, only one settings.gradle file can be used at a time. Since project B depends on C and project B is part of the multi-project build, you need to include project C in any settings.gradle file that uses project B (assuming you're using project dependencies instead of artifact dependencies).

Note that you can tell Gradle which settings.gradle file to use for each build with the [`-c` command line option](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/gradle_command_line.html), but the build for A is never going to work unless B and all of its project dependencies are included.

Also note that multi-project builds always define a single "root" project, which is defined by where the settings.gradle file is. So if project A contains settings.gradle, it is the "root" project. However, in a flat layout, you can create a special directory named `master` to represent this and Gradle will automatically find your settings.gradle file there. [Read about this here.](http://www.gradle.org/docs/1.12/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec%3ainitialization) Note that all of your build commands should typically be run from the "root" project, so if you use the Gradle wrapper, it should live there.

Assuming a flat layout, I would suggest this structure:

```
A/
  build.gradle
  src/
    main/
      java/
B/
  build.gradle
  src/
    main/
      java/
C/
  build.gradle
  src/
    main/
      java/
master/
  build.gradle
  gradle/
    wrapper/
      gradle-wrapper.jar
      gradle-wrapper.properties
  gradlew
  gradlew.bat
  settings.gradle
```

And the contents of settings.gradle would be something like:

```
["A", "B", "C"].each {
    includeFlat it
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. To be sure I understand well: 1) this basically means that every project "includeFlat"s all the others, whether it needs them or not. 2) once I do this, then the build will actually work transitively, that is: `compile project(':B')` will eventually trigger the build of C.

Comment: Hold on, do I really (physically) change the layout of my workspace and have a master project on top of them all? I really don't like this. Is there another way to accomplish the same? I guess one is to replicate the same `settings.gradle` to each project. Not very elegant..

Comment: **1)** Yes. Just because they are included in the multi-project build doesn't mean project A needs to know anything about project C. **2)** Yes, building A will implicitly build project B, which will implicitly build project C. **3)** You don't have to have a `master` project (would be at same level as others), but you probably should use only a single `settings.gradle` file, which should go in your designated "root" project. You could then rely on using the `-c` flag to run builds from other projects, but I don't know how well that would integrate with Eclipse.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't notice that `master` would be at the same level. Thanks!

Comment: However this still seems pretty inconvenient. If I have a `master` project with `includeFlat 'A', 'B', 'C'` in settings.gradle (tried this, works great - thanks), then all these projects must actually exist on disk, I suppose. Which forces me to check them all out from my repository, even when - say - I'm working on my laptop and could check out only a couple of them. Am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct. If you want to build them separately, then I would recommend using artifact dependencies instead.

Comment: @comuz Maybe you could write an expression to detect the presence of the sibling folder and, if present, 'compile project' otherwise 'compile <artifact>'